# Plotting functions in Julia suddenly doesn't work

Tags: function, plot, julia

Yesterday I was playing with Julia, plotting various different functions and variables. And suddenly a very important feature stopped working. I cant plot a function with a simple "plot(f)" command. I would love some help, because this features simplifies my work greatly.

I tried to recompile the packages I used, yet it didn't help any.
I need to plot distributions and also my own functions (one variable).
I'm using packages Distributions.jl and StatsPlots.jl

There's a simple example that I know did work - but now it doesn't:

```
using Distributions
using StatsPlots
f(x) = x^2
plot(f)
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  Float64(::Int8) at float.jl:60
  Float64(::Int16) at float.jl:60
  Float64(::Int32) at float.jl:60
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::getfield(Plots, Symbol("##108#109")){Symbol})(::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\axes.jl:152
 [2] _broadcast_getindex at .\broadcast.jl:578 [inlined]
 [3] (::getfield(Base.Broadcast, Symbol("##19#20")){Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.Style{Tuple},Nothing,getfield(Plots, Symbol("##108#109")){Symbol},Tuple{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}}}})(::Int64) at .\broadcast.jl:953
 [4] ntuple at .\tuple.jl:160 [inlined]
 [5] copy at .\broadcast.jl:953 [inlined]
 [6] materialize(::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.Style{Tuple},Nothing,getfield(Plots, Symbol("##108#109")){Symbol},Tuple{Tuple{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}}}) at .\broadcast.jl:753
 [7] _scaled_adapted_grid(::Function, ::Symbol, ::Symbol, ::Float64, ::Float64) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\series.jl:542
 [8] macro expansion at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\series.jl:529 [inlined]
 [9] apply_recipe(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Function, ::Float64, ::Float64) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\RecipesBase\zBoFG\src\RecipesBase.jl:275
 [10] _process_userrecipes(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{typeof(f)}) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\pipeline.jl:83
 [11] _plot!(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{typeof(f)}) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\plot.jl:178
 [12] #plot#137(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Function) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\plot.jl:57
 [13] plot(::Function) at C:\Users\masen\.julia\packages\Plots\47Tik\src\plot.jl:51
 [14] top-level scope at none:0
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this error.

Comment: Well, it's some kind of internal error that you probably won't be able to replicate. But I'm not a master at reading Julia's error messages nor am I a person who can see deeply in the language itself - and I thought maybe someone more experienced might know what's going on.

Comment: A more minimal example would be `using Plots; plot(x -> x^2)`, which fails with the same error.

Comment: This seems to work on Plots master; can you try restarting Julia, pasting `]add Plots#master` into the REPL, and rerun the example?

Comment: @MichaelaMašková what is your Plots version? Can you try `]free Plots`, then `up` then try again? We may need to push a new version, but I believe this is just a version mismatch between PlotUtils and Plots